How come it's okay to assign multiple times to an immutable variable?
Note - Following is a contract that successfully compiled.
In this contract's constructor, I have clearly assigned multiple times to x.
Why is this okay? What's happening here?

// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.26;

contract IsThisImmutable {

    uint public s_a = 0;

    uint256 public immutable x;

    constructor() {
        x = 134;
        x += 3;
        s_a += x;
        x += 3;
    }

    function exp1(uint256 a) public returns(uint256) {
        s_a += a;
        s_a += x;
        return 34;
    }

    modifier modifier1 {
        _;
        s_a += 1023;
        return;
    }


}




It’s okay because you’re assigning value to x multiple times within the constructor itself, so the state change is only considered one time i.e., the final value that’s being assigned to it in the constructor.

But I can see that already...

Why is it considered only one time ? we have multiple sstore calls right ?

No SSTORE call is made, as immutable variables are stored in the contract bytecode, not in storage.

I'd also assume compiler optimizes this to only one assignment.
